# Missing Ray visibility and ambient occulsion settings

Tags: world

I recently downloaded and installed blender 2.83.3 and couldn't find the Ray visibility, ambient occulsion, volume and settings in the World properties section.

These options were available in 2.83 but I can't seem to find them in 2.83.3, I'm wondering if I have a glitch copy

Comment: Hello :). Nothing wrong with your copy. Blender comes with Eevee render engine by default, just switch to Cycles engine and it will all be there.

Comment: I just knew, it solution will end up being something so simple 

Comment: I feel so disappointed in my self right now. Thank you so much Jachym Michal I need to put in more time in learning this amazing software.

Comment: Don't feel discouraged, you can't know everything :). Welcome to Blender and good luck with your project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ray Visibility and Ambient Occlusion are only available when you set cycles as render engine.

[image]